# Kafka Consumer is not working with transactional semantics (isolation.level = read_commited)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Kafka Consumer is not able to consume any message when it's having transactional semantics in properties. But when I remove that property or update that property to read_uncommited, its consuming messages.

Below is my Kafka Consumer Properties:-

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.2.200.15:9092");
    String consumeGroup = "cg3";
    props.put("group.id", consumeGroup);
    // Below is a key setting to turn off the auto commit.
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
    props.put("heartbeat.interval.ms", "2000");
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "6001");
    // Control maximum data on each poll, make sure this value is bigger than the
    // maximum // single message size
    props.put("max.partition.fetch.bytes", "140");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("isolation.level","read_committed");
```

Kafka Producer is having a Transactional id in its properties and after pushing some messages it is committing transaction as a whole.  Below is the Kafka Producer Properties:-

log.info("Initializing Properties");
        Properties props = new Properties();

```
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, System.getenv(KafkaConstants.KAFKA_URL));
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("linger.ms", 1000);
    props.put("acks", "all");
    // props.put("request.timeout.ms",30000);
    props.put("retries", 3);
    props.put("retry.backoff.ms", 1000);
    props.put("max.in.flight.requests.per.connection", 1); // if its greater than 1, it can change the order or records. Maximum no. of unacknowledge request a client can send.
    props.put("enable.idempotence", true);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG,"Transaction8");
```

Below snippet is responsible to commit transactions :-

```
public boolean send(ProducerRecordImpl record) {
    try {
        producer.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {


            Future<RecordMetadata> futureResult = producer
                    .send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(record.getTopic(), record.getPayload()));
            /*
             * It will wait till the thread execution completes and return true.
             */
            //RecordMetadata ack = futureResult.get();
            //log.debug("RecordMetadta offset {} and partiton {} ", ack.offset(), ack.partition());
        }
        producer.commitTransaction();
        log.info("Commited");


        return true;
```

I am not able to understand whether commit is not happening properly from the Producer Side which leads to Kafka Consumer not able to read it with a transactional semantics or problem perists with Kafka Consumer side.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I drilled down the issue and found out that my last stable offset is at 45. But my current offset in the consumer side is 365. So read_commited will read only from last stable offset, when i changed my current offset to 30 , Kafka Consumer starts consuming messages with read_commited property.

Comment: So my Question is why my last stable offset is not getting updated by Kafka Producer when i am commiting the transaction from that side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call producer.initTransactions() first. Otherwise your producer is not publishing transactional messages.

From https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#initTransactions()

> Needs to be called before any other methods when the transactional.id
>   is set in the configuration. This method does the following: 1.
>   Ensures any transactions initiated by previous instances of the
>   producer with the same transactional.id are completed. If the previous
>   instance had failed with a transaction in progress, it will be
>   aborted. If the last transaction had begun completion, but not yet
>   finished, this method awaits its completion. 2. Gets the internal
>   producer id and epoch, used in all future transactional messages
>   issued by the producer.

Comment: props.put("retries", 3);
  props.put("retry.backoff.ms", 1000);
  props.put("max.in.flight.requests.per.connection", 1); // if its greater than 1, it can change the order or records. Maximum no. of unacknowledge request a client can send.
  props.put("enable.idempotence", true);
  props.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG,"Transaction15");

Comment: private KafkaTemplate() {
  log.info("Instantiation of Kafka Producer ");
  producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(initializeProducerProperties());
  producer.initTransactions();
 }

Comment: Do you have a 3 node kafka cluster to publish against? Is the __transaction_state topic being created with replication  factor of 3?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when testing Transactions on Kafka. The problem was the operating system. I was using Windows 10 to run Kafka brokers, and the consumer couldn't see any committed transactions when they were configure as "read_committed", once I move the brokers to Linux, the transaction (and the consumers) started working.
By the way, Kafka didn't show me any error in the logs.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This issue is irrelevant to operating system. This issue is more related to the way kafka producer is committing the message.